# How Scraping Table Web-Site with Button "Option value"?

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-firefoxdriver

In particular I am trying to scrap this table (https://whalewisdom.com/filer/berkshire-hathaway-inc#tabholdings_tab_link) But I would like to scraping via python code, the first 50 rows.

For this reason I need to setup option value in order to see the first 50 rows per pages:

[image]

my currently code are:

```
test = {}
dict_scr = {}
for ii in range (0,12):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.binary_location = r'C:/Users/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
    driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:/Users/geckodriver.exe' , options=options)
    driver.execute("get", {'url': link_scr['Links'][ii]})

Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='50']"))))

    test[link_scr.index[ii]] = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#current_holdings_table"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
    dict_scr[link_scr.index[ii]]  = pd.read_html(test[link_scr.index[ii]])
    print(test[link_scr.index[ii]])
```

How I can modify this code in order to get firs 50 rows scraping dataframe?

Comment: you can use find_elements to get all similar elements in one page

Comment: Can you give me an example code?

Answer (score 0):

I write two samples, you can refer to [github](https://github.com/automation9417/automation-samples/tree/main/whalewisdom):

sample:

```
from time import sleep
from clicknium import clicknium as cc, locator

tab = cc.chrome.open("https://whalewisdom.com/filer/berkshire-hathaway-inc#tabholdings_tab_link")
tab.find_element(locator.chrome.whalewisdom.button_25).click()
tab.find_element(locator.chrome.whalewisdom.a_50).click()

sleep(3) #wait for table laoded

elems_sector = tab.find_elements(locator.chrome.whalewisdom.td_informationtechnology)
elemns_shares = tab.find_elements(locator.chrome.whalewisdom.td_890923410)

count = len(elems_sector)
for idx in range(count):
    sector = elems_sector[idx].get_text()
    shares = elemns_shares[idx].get_text()
    print({'sector': sector, 'shares': shares})
```

sample1: don't change page number, scrape two pages data

```
from time import sleep
from clicknium import clicknium as cc, locator

tab = cc.chrome.open("https://whalewisdom.com/filer/berkshire-hathaway-inc#tabholdings_tab_link")

i = 0

while True:
    elems_sector = tab.find_elements(locator.chrome.whalewisdom.td_informationtechnology)
    elemns_shares = tab.find_elements(locator.chrome.whalewisdom.td_890923410)

    count = len(elems_sector)
    for idx in range(count):
        sector = elems_sector[idx].get_text()
        shares = elemns_shares[idx].get_text()
        print({'sector': sector, 'shares': shares})
    i += 1
    if i>1:
        break
    tab.find_element(locator.chrome.whalewisdom.a).click()
    sleep(2) #wait for table loaded
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I use FireFox can you change the code ? thanks

Comment: you can just change the code chrome to firefox, it should be ok

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clicknium'

Comment: you need follow the readme  to setup env and run sample,  after you run the sample successful,  if do other autoamtion,you can use the recorder to record web ui element